# in ReactJS, how to persist a value between renders without re-rendering component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

How can I persist a value between renders without the function component being re-rendered every time the value is changed?

```
function TotalNumberComponent() {
  const [totalNumber, setTotalNumber] = useState(0);

  let color = 'red';

  if (totalNumber % 10 === 9) color = 'green';
}
```

I don't want `TotalNumberComponent()` to be re-rendered when color is changed, so I can't use the `useState` hook for color, but I still want to keep color value after `TotalNumberComponent()` is re-rendered.

Comment: time to learn about useRef() hook, please view the docs https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef

Comment: That's kind of the whole point of `useState`, if you don't want a render, like pointed out above by @Saraf  you can use `useRef`..

Comment: Why do you want to change the value without re-rendering the component?

Comment: "*I don't want TotalNumberComponent() to be re-rendered when color is changed*" - are you referring to the `color = 'green'` "change" or something else?

Comment: "*I still want to keep color value after TotalNumberComponent() is re-rendered due to totalNumber's change.*" - I don't understand. would `color` always stay `'red'` then because it keeps the initial value it has been "initialised" with when `color` was `0`?

Comment: @Bergi: I deleted the comment earlier because comment doesn't fully support markdown and my example code looks messy in the comment. I just edited the question as you suggested.

Comment: @JessicaWang Thanks. Can you answer my two questions regarding the `TotalNumberComponet`?

Comment: @Bergi: 
> are you referring to the color = 'green' 
Yes. I'm referring to when color changes to 'green', I don't want TotalNumberComponent() is re-rendered again.
My example code is not a good example, because when color will change to green, totalNumber must have been changed to 9, 19, 29, etc, TotalNumberComponent()  will be re-rendered anyway.

Comment: @JessicaWang Yes, indeed. And `color` is just a local variable in the function, it only exists during the function call when the component is rendered. It is created anew for each render, it is not kept between renders. And changing it will indeed not trigger a re-rendering. So what do you want to persist, and why?

Comment: @Bergi: The feature I'm working on has the need to persist a value after the component is re-rendered, but changing the value itself should not re-render the component.
The feature is on a web form which has a bunch of input fields.
When clicking on each input field, a variable "totalNumberOfTouchedFields" should be increased by 1.
There is a button on the web form. When the button is clicked, the component should be re-rendered and we still want to keep the value in variable "totalNumberOfTouchedFields".

Comment: In that case, `useRef(0)` is what you are looking for. Though it shouldn't hurt to store it in a state either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { useRef } from "react"
        
function favoriteColor() {
    // remove useState
    // const [color, setColor] = useState("");
    const colorRef = useRef("");
    // instead of setColor("red")
    colorRef.current = "red"
}

// and you can use it like:
<p>{colorRef.current}</p>
```